# Azure Key Vault configuration section in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I am implementing Azure Key Vault in a .NET Core ASP.NET project. I am trying to create a configuration section in the vault for secrets, but the syntax `SectionName:KeyName` (which works for App Service configuration) is not allowed for a secret name. Does it mean that ASP.NET Core Configuration sections are not supported for secrets in a Key Vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default key delimiter on Azure Key Vault is double dash. Therefore, renaming your key to `SectionName--KeyName` should work.

According with [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-a-key-name-prefix), you should be able to change the key delimiter.

Comment: Yes, it really works with double dash. Thank you.